# Which kind of datatype should I use for Pipe thikness Field?

Tags: c#

i have a project that should save Pipe thikness Value in Database
i have a table in sql server : Piping {id:int , thk:float}
in c#  : float PipeThk;

i use this but when i store PipeThk in table Piping field thk it has some thing like this value :
2.32356456456
in my case the number is not very importnat and pipe thk is just a number with 2 precision so i should save this in database just 2.3(example) not 2/299999952316284.
i read all about decimal vs float vs double . decimal is good but in memory usage is very higher than float.i care the perfromance.
now can anyone say me what should id do?

i try float and double . float is less memry usage and decimal use much memory usage.

Comment: "decimal is good but in memory usage is very higher than float" - how many pipe thicknesses will you be storing? Millions?

Comment: what unit is the diameter in? floats have 6 to 7 digits precision, that should be enough for a real world measurement I think.

Comment: i should save 6000 to 8000 pipe thk record save.

Comment: 8000 rows is a complete non-issue. Suppose each pipe took 100 bytes to store (an outrageous number, given the precision); then you'd have a grand total of 800 KB worth of data -- significant in 1970 perhaps, but today, your application executable alone is probably larger than that. Use the types that are appropriate for your data domain, worry about storage when you need to. In this case, you don't need to.